# Como inserir um elemento apenas uma vez com evento jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Estou criando uma validação em jQuery e quando o campo perde o foco ele verifica se está vazio e insere a mensagem de erro, mais toda vez que acontece esse evento insere a mesma mensagem. Como fazer isso sem essa repetição?

Queria fazer algo similar ao jquery-validate...

Meu código é esse:

```js
$(function() {
  var $form = $("#formtest");
  $("#nome").on('blur', function() {
    var $this   = $("#nome"),
        $value  = $this.val();

    if ($value == "") {
      $form.submit(function() {
        return false;
      });
      if ($this.hasClass('.error')) {
        $this.removeClass("erro");
        $("small").remove();
      } else {
        $this.addClass("erro");
        $this.after("<small class='erro'>Preencha seu nome!</small>");

      }
    } else {
      $this.removeClass("erro");
      $("small.erro").remove();
      alert("tudo certo!");
      $form.submit(function() {
        return true;
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input.erro {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.erro {
  color: red;
  padding-left: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formtest">
  <label>Nome</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="nome" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Uma solução interessante

Desta forma basta colocar `data-required="Preencha seu nome!"` no input text que você desejar colocando a mensagem de erro e assim você não vai precisar mais modificar o javascript para os novos campos que criar, e também você pode criar novas validações personalizadas com a mesma ideia.

**Resultado**

> Os comentários do código estão explicando o seu funcionamento

```js
//Função para cuidar da mensagem de erro
function setaMensagem(seletor, mensagem){

  //Verifica se já existe uma mensagem de erro
  if(seletor.next().attr("class") == 'erro'){
    seletor.next().text(mensagem); //Se existir apenas seta a mensagem
  }else{
    seletor.after("<small class='erro'>" + mensagem + "</small>");//Se não cria uma mensagem nova
  }
}

function validar(element){
    if(element.val().length <= 0){
      setaMensagem(element, element.data('required'));
      return false;
    }else{
      setaMensagem(element, "");
      return true;
    }
}

$(function() {
  $("[data-required]").on('blur', function() {
    validar($(this));
  });
  $('#formtest').submit(function() {
    return validar($("[data-required]"));
  });
})
```

```css
input.erro {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.erro {
  color: red;
  padding-left: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formtest">
  <label>Nome</label>
  <br>
  
  <input 
  type="text"  
  id="nome" 
  value="" 
  data-required="Preencha seu nome!">
  <!-- Defino apenas a mensagem de erro -->
  
  <small class='erro'></small>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

## Solucionando utilizando o seu código

**Mensagem de erro vermelha**

Para que a mensagem de erro seja setada apenas uma vez eu coloquei diretamente no html a tag

```
<small class='erro'></small>
```

Como ela esta vazia ela não estará visível, e no código `Javascript` eu coloquei da seguinte forma

```
$this.next().text("Preencha seu nome!");
```

Ele pega o próximo elemento utilizando o método `next`, que neste caso é a tag `small` e seta o texto, caso ele sete de novo ele substituir o texto anterior não repetindo assim o texto.

E por fim eu substituir o seguinte trecho

```
$("small").remove();
```

por

```
$("small").text("");
```

Assim ele apenas manipula o texto, já que o small sem texto como dito acima não aparece caso não haja um o texto.

**Alert**

Mas caso você queira limitar também o `alert`, criei uma flag com uma variável como fiz no caso "tudoCerto", assim o `alert` apareça somente uma vez.

O funcionamento é simples, a flag é setada com verdadeiro, e ao apresentar a mensagem ela e setada como falsa, caso o evento seja chamado novamente a mensagem não aparece já que a flag estará falsa.

**Resultado**

```js
$(function() {
  var tudoCerto = true;
  var $form = $("#formtest");
  $("#nome").on('blur', function() {
    var $this   = $("#nome"),
        $value  = $this.val();

    if ($value == "") {
      $form.submit(function() {
        return false;
      });
      if ($this.hasClass('.error')) {
        $this.removeClass("erro");
      } else {
        $this.addClass("erro");
        $this.next().text("Preencha seu nome!");

      }
    } else {
      $this.removeClass("erro");
      $("small.erro").text("");
      if(tudoCerto){
        alert("tudo certo!");
        tudoCerto = false;
      }
      
      $form.submit(function() {
        return true;
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input.erro {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.erro {
  color: red;
  padding-left: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formtest">
  <label>Nome</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="nome" value="">
  <small class='erro'></small>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: obrigado por sua resposta também, um método realmente interessante, só não entendi no seu exemplo, porque o data-required você passou a mensagem e depois teve que passar de novo dentro da função, não era pra pegar dinamicamente a mensagem do data-required?

Comment: Outra coisa que esqueci de pergunta na minha pergunta, da pra verificar isso quando aperta o submit também?

Comment: Terminei de fazer as alterações :)

Comment: Agora ele puxa o valor do data-required e também verifica antes de da o submit :)

Comment: Perfeito, você me salvou mesmo! agora posso fazer meu propio metodo

Comment: Ótimo! Qualquer dúvida é só comentar, e por favor, marque a pergunta como respondida :)

Comment: sou novo aqui, como que faz isso ^^

Comment: Você pode aperta o botão de seta para cima para avaliar as respostas que você gostou, ou seja, você pode votar em quantas respostas quiser com um voto positivo, mas embaixo há um "V", no qual você marca a melhor resposta para você.

Comment: Pronto, agora pra fica perfeito, como eu daria o foco pro botão que está errado mais na ordem certa!, eu tentei aqui adicionando um ´element.focus()´ mais ele mostra fora de ordem...

Comment: Você tem dois botões, um do lado do outro, e quando você aperta tab ele da foco botão errado, é isso?

Comment: Quando aperto o submit ele foca o outro exato...

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer aperta submit, e o foco ir para o campo caso dê erro?

Comment: Exatamente, só que eu tenho uns 10 campos pra verificar, ai ele não vai pro 1 ele vai pro segundo... será que vai ter q ter um for()... se tiver que ter, não tenho muita noção de como fazer...

Comment: Acho que isso foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta, acho melhor você criar uma nova pergunta para isso, porque assim a próxima pessoa que estiver com o mesmo problema seu vai consegui pesquisar por isso, crie a nova pergunta explicando o sua dificuldade, e poste o link aqui

Comment: Verdade, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A **ÚNICA coisa** que precisa fazer é trocar a linha `$("small").remove();` de lugar, colocando-a antes do `if`:

```js
$(function() {
  var $form = $("#formtest");
  $("#nome").on('blur', function() {
    var $this   = $("#nome"),
        $value  = $this.val();

    if ($value == "") {
      $form.submit(function() {
        return false;
      });
      // COLOQUE AQUI. Irá remover se existir
      $("small").remove();
      if ($this.hasClass('.error')) {
        $this.removeClass("erro");
      } else {
        $this.addClass("erro");
        $this.after("<small class='erro'>Preencha seu nome!</small>");

      }
    } else {
      $this.removeClass("erro");
      $("small.erro").remove();
      alert("tudo certo!");
      $form.submit(function() {
        return true;
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input.erro {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.erro {
  color: red;
  padding-left: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formtest">
  <label>Nome</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="nome" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta, ajudou demais! queria entender essa lógica de ele ter que ser antes pra verificar, consegui explicar?

Comment: esqueci de perguntar, como faz pra verificar quando aperta o submit também...?